# Boost Logging displays linux thread ids as all 0s

Tags: linux, boost, boost-log, powerpc

I am trying to send log strings to a file in the latest version of boost 1.57  and for some reason on linux, the thread IDs are always set to 0's.  I have a feeling that it may have something to do with using native threads instead of boost threads - but that doesn't explain why it works in the windows environment.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my initialization code in logger.cpp file.

**EDIT**: shown below I have also included my Logger.h which show the type of logger I use - effectively using the BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV macro to log to a

> boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt< boost::log::trivial::severity_level >

```
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/scoped_attribute.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/manipulators/add_value.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>

. . .

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace trivial = boost::log::trivial;
void
Logger::init(
    const fs::path& rErrEvtPath,
    const fs::path& rStatusPath)
{
    // register common attributes - ThreadID, LineID, TimeStamp etc.
    logging::add_common_attributes();

    // Construct the sink for the "event_log" channel
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<
        sinks::text_ostream_backend> text_sink;
    auto sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
    sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>(rErrEvtPath.c_str()));
    sink->set_formatter(
        expr::format("%1% [%2%] tid[%3%] %4%")
        % expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
        % logging::trivial::severity
        % expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
        % expr::smessage);
    sink->set_filter(expr::attr<std::string>("Channel") == "event");
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

    // Construct the sink for the "status_log" channel
    sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
    sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>(rStatusPath.c_str()));
    sink->set_formatter(
        expr::format("%1% [%2%] tid[%3%] %4%")
        % expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
        % logging::trivial::severity
        % expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID")
        % expr::smessage);
    sink->set_filter(expr::attr<std::string>("Channel") == "status");
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}
```

Logs on windows display just fine i.e.

```
15:42:35.205747 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] SETCNTX IP_ADDR 192.168.1.1
15:42:35.207747 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] SETCNTX RESP_ON
15:42:35.209747 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] SETCNTX SET_FTP_TIMEOUT 10
15:42:35.212747 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] FTPNOPROMPT [192.168.1.1] [timeout 10(s)]
15:42:35.552781 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] SETCNTX RESP_OFF
15:42:35.553781 [info] tid[0x00000e14] module[NIC:192.168.1.1] FTPQUOTE "site attrib 0 DEOS"
```

however on linux (ppc) using the same version of boost 1.57.0 the logs are as follows:

```
13:43:45.092206 [info] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] MLFCommand - command group(5) - end
13:43:45.092568 [info] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] SETCNTX IP_ADDR 192.168.1.23
13:43:45.097037 [info] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] SETCNTX RESP_ON
13:43:45.098691 [info] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] SETCNTX SET_FTP_TIMEOUT 10
13:43:45.100474 [info] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] FTPNOPROMPT [192.168.1.23] [timeout 10(s)]
13:43:49.191856 [warning] tid[0000000000] module[N/A] [>TIMEOUT<]
```

EDIT: for completeness - I include logger.h

```
#ifndef _logger_h_
#define _logger_h_

// SYSTEM INCLUDES
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#if !defined(__GNUC__)
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4714 4100 4510 4503 4512 4610)
#endif
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>
#if !defined(__GNUC__)
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif

// APPLICATION INCLUDES
// DEFINES
#define LOG(logger, lvl) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", lvl)
#define LOG_TRACE(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::trace)
#define LOG_DEBUG(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::debug)
#define LOG_INFO(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::info)
#define LOG_WARNING(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::warning)
#define LOG_ERROR(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::error)
#define LOG_FATAL(logger) BOOST_LOG_CHANNEL_SEV(logger, "event", trivial::fatal)

// MACROS
// EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS
extern bool gVerboseMode;

// EXTERNAL VARIABLES
// CONSTANTS
// STRUCTS
// TYPEDEFS
// FORWARD DECLARATIONS

class Logger
{
public:
    using SEVChannelLoggerMT = boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<
        boost::log::trivial::severity_level>;
    /**
     * singleton pattern implementation
     *
     * @return singleton instance
     */
    static Logger* getInstance();

    // destructor
    virtual ~Logger() = default;

    /** define a log filter associated with a channel attribute */
    enum class LogDest {
        EventLog, StatusLog
    };

    /**
     * log the message to a specified log<p>
     *
     * @param logDest  [in] filter used to route the log message to
     *                 the correct logging sink.
     * @param rMessage [in] message to log
     */
    void logMessage(
       const LogDest logDest,
       const boost::log::trivial::severity_level& severity,
       const std::string& rMessage);

    /**
     * Returns logger associated with the specified log destination.<p>
     *
     * @param logDest  [in] filter used to route the log message to
     *                 the correct logging sink.
     * @return logger of the appropriate type
     */
    SEVChannelLoggerMT& getLoggerRef(const LogDest logDest);

    /**
     * Custom reusable formatter which we can attach to all sinks
     * for a uniform formatting of log messages
     *
     * @param rec    [in] record contain the log details
     * @param strm   [in,out] logging stream
     */
    static void customFormatter(
        boost::log::record_view const& rec,
        boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm);

    /**
     * Initialize the logging framework.<p>
     * Initializes the Boost logging framework by setting up the
     * following log files<p>.
     * Under the covers the Boost Logging framework initializes two
     * distinct log files.
     * <ul>
     *     <li>Error/Event log - this contains everything</li>
     *     <li>rStatusPath - high level log file which is also
     *     displayed on the iPad</li>
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param rErrEvtPath
     *               [in] fully qualified path to
     *               DlfLogBuffer[num].txt log file.  This log
     *               file will be created as necessary or
     *               reinitialized to empty (truncated) if it
     *               already exists.
     * @param rStatusPath
     *               [in] fully qualified path to
     *               DlfStatusBuffer[num].txt log file.  This log
     *               file will be created as necessary or
     *               reinitialized to empty (truncated) if it
     *               already exists.
     */
    static void init(
        const boost::filesystem::path& rErrEvtPath,
        const boost::filesystem::path& rStatusPath);
private:
    // severity channel loggers - one for the error event log
    SEVChannelLoggerMT m_event_logger, m_status_logger;

    /**
     * Constructor - initialize each channel logger with a named
     * channel attribute which will be used by filtering to route
     * logging records to the appropriate sink.
     */
    Logger();
    // singleton and locking support
    static std::mutex gMutexGuard;
    static Logger* gpInstance;
};

#endif // _logger_h_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to report this upstream (or debug it manually).

**Update** The issue has been reported to the Boost Log devs and they have fixed it (thanks @johnco3)

Here's the same on Debian:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru (Debian)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/effb7480fd0d5707)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/scoped_attribute.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/channel_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/keywords/channel.hpp>
#include <boost/log/keywords/severity.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/manipulators/add_value.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/console.hpp>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

namespace fs       = boost::filesystem;
namespace logging  = boost::log;
namespace src      = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr     = boost::log::expressions;
namespace sinks    = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs    = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace trivial  = boost::log::trivial;

struct Logger {
    void init(const fs::path &rErrEvtPath, const fs::path &rStatusPath) {
        // register common attributes - ThreadID, LineID, TimeStamp etc.
        logging::add_common_attributes();

        // Construct the sink for the "event_log" channel
        typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend> text_sink;
        auto sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
        sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
        sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>(rErrEvtPath.c_str()));
        sink->set_formatter(expr::format("%1% [%2%] tid[%3%] %4%") %
                            expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f") %
                            logging::trivial::severity % expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID") %
                            expr::smessage);
        sink->set_filter(expr::attr<std::string>("Channel") == "event");
        logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

        // Construct the sink for the "status_log" channel
        sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();
        sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
        sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>(rStatusPath.c_str()));
        sink->set_formatter(expr::format("%1% [%2%] tid[%3%] %4%") %
                            expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f") %
                            logging::trivial::severity % expr::attr<attrs::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID") %
                            expr::smessage);
        sink->set_filter(expr::attr<std::string>("Channel") == "status");
        logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
    }
};

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_CTOR_ARGS(statuc_lg,
        src::severity_channel_logger_mt< >, (keywords::severity = trivial::error)(keywords::channel = "status"))
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_CTOR_ARGS(event_lg,
        src::severity_channel_logger_mt< >, (keywords::severity = trivial::error)(keywords::channel = "event"))

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main()
{
    Logger l;
    l.init("test.1", "test.2");

    boost::thread_group tg;
    tg.create_thread([]{
            BOOST_LOG(statuc_lg::get()) << "this is a status update";
            BOOST_LOG(event_lg::get()) << "this is an event"; });
    tg.create_thread([]{
            BOOST_LOG(statuc_lg::get()) << "this is a status update";
            BOOST_LOG(event_lg::get()) << "this is an event"; });

    tg.join_all();
}
```

Results:

```
==> test.1 <==
23:55:58.635779 [] tid[0x00007f26d9a65700] this is an event
23:55:58.635832 [] tid[0x00007f26d9264700] this is an event

==> test.2 <==
23:55:58.635367 [] tid[0x00007f26d9a65700] this is a status update
23:55:58.635540 [] tid[0x00007f26d9264700] this is a status update
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example and live Coliru example. I won't get a chance to test this out on my target platform until Monday.  Do you know what was wrong with my implementation?  Mine worked on windows, but not on my PowerPC embedded target platform.  Also slightly related but do you know if there is anyway to force the sink to generate CRLF line endings on a platform that uses LFs, users want to look at these log files using notepad and I would rather not have to run dos2unix on the log files after they have been generated.

Comment: @johnco3 I don't know what was wrong. I actually think my sample will probably show the same behaviour, in which case it's /just/ a bug report :) I'd teach the users to use sane editors (Notepad++ and many others are free). There's always `wordpad.exe`. And finally, I don't think there's a way in Boost/standard library to make line ends behave non-native

Comment: thanks for the both the detailed answer & comment response, I will let you know about the logging thread IDs on Monday - and if it fixes the problems I'll check the answered box - fingers crossed!

Comment: I thought that the problem might have had something to do with boost::threads or the presence of the BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK macro, so I made updated your coliru example using my actual code and the problem unfortunately persists on my target embedded PPC platform.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55e4b334188c978d Not very important but not quite sure why the second log is empty (it has nothing to do wtih the thread id) which is alwys 8 blank zeros without an leading 0x per "12:22:54.630043 [info] tid[0000000000] info text message goes here"  I dont really know how to debug it further.

Comment: You can always debug by single stepping. However, what you probably mean is, you will end up finding a limitation/bug anyways. In that vein, you could file a bug, with a minimal SSCCE attached, stating that platform and toolchain versions

Comment: I contacted the LogBoost author, and he fixed it upstream - Yeah!  The problem turned out to related to both endian-ness and the size of pthread_t types & uintmax_t types.  Tricky!

Comment: @johnco3 Brilliant. Thanks for reporting back. I'll add a note to my answer